# If $(Y_n)$ is an adapted sequence of random variables, with $EY_T = 0$, show $EY_n = 0$ for all $n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

Let $(Y_n)$ be an adapted sequence of integrable ranodm variables, with the property that for every boudned stopping time $T$ we have $EY_T = 0$. I am asked to show that $EY_n = 0$ for every natural number $n$. I have tried:

Suppose that the stopping time is bounded, say by $K$, then we can write:

$$Y_n = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} Y_i 1_{\{T = i\}} + 1_{\{T \geq k \}}Y_k$$

by the definition of stopping time, each $1_{\{T = i\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ measurable, and similarly $1_{\{T\geq k\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ measurable, now I wanted to take $E(Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{k-1})$ and get some sort of conclusion but I can't proceed

Answer (score 0):

Each nonnegative integer $n$ corresponds to a bounded stopping time ($T = n$ a.s.).

Comment: thanks, I understand the idea of why it works, but I am trying to formualise it. The solutions I have say the same as you.

Comment: would it be right to say $Y_n = 1_{\{T=n\}} Y_T?$

Comment: If $T$ is the constant $n$, then $Y_T = Y_n$.  You don't need the $1_{\{T=n\}}$.